# How to use jQuery on my page?

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I'm following this tutorial but it doesn't tell me how to run this jQuery script. Since this script will be run pretty much everywhere, I should attach this script to the Masterpage right, but how?

I guess what I'm asking is, what HTML tag do I need to reference the jQuery script, and where to put the jQuery code.

I have this library already in my project:
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Why the downvotes? I believe this a perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: @Sergio Tapia - you might want to link the tutorial you're looking at.

Comment: Not that I've voted on this but unfortunately Russell our voting intentions aren't dependent on what *you* think is reasonable.

Comment: No but when I refer to reasonable, I was refering to the question meeting the requirements of the FAQ.

Comment: I am one of those who voted down. The reason is that it's also an ASP specific question and the technology wasn't mentioned anywhere... Unfortunately I am not used to the Visual Studio and so I wasn't able to guess the technology from the screenshot.

Comment: @tux21b so move along quietly, no need to downvote. Last time I looked an inability to guess an unfamiliar technology was not a valid purpose of downvoting.

Comment: Comments are intended to be used for clarification, and voting down for misinformation. The PO did not have any misinformation in the question. A comment to request clarification would be more helpful to the PO (and others) so they have a greater chance of an answer to their questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery is a client-side scripting tool. ASP .Net is a server-side language.

You are correct, to add a reference to jQuery for all pages it is a good idea to use a master page for this purpose.

In the master page, you simply add the HTML script reference to the master page:

```
<@ MasterPage .... >

<html>
<head>
  <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="Content" />
</body>
</html>
```

Add a script element for each of the jQuery scripts. Make sure the jquery-1.4.1.js is the first referenced though.

Also make sure you use the `<script></script>` instead of `<script/>` due to some browser issues.

Some newer Visual Studio MVC project files do this script referencing for you (as Lenial mentioned), and this may be easier.